# Get recyclerview item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout, in which RecyclerView and a view is used. View is overlapping the RecyclerView at centre. I  want to get the position of item  at position of view when scroll or when recyclerview scroll stops.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get the item position.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int itemPoition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }
});
```